# Can GitHub Apps access users' private emails when GitHub Oauth Apps Cannot?

Tags: github-api

I'd like to see if someone can help me figure out if I can fetch the *private* email of a GitHub user who is authenticating via GitHub OAuth. Example permissions page for my GitHub OAuth app:

[image: screenshot]

Here, after the user provides permission then allows my backend to fetch their profile, the 'email' field of a [user](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/users/users?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-the-authenticated-user) can be `null` if that user marks their email as "private" in their profile, even if using the [`user:email`](https://docs.github.com/en/apps/oauth-apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps#available-scopes) scope, which makes complete sense.

Now enter a site like [railway.app](https://railway.app), if one tries to sign up, their service *relies* on being able to email users, and when I test their sign up, even though my GitHub email is private, they are able to obtain my email at sign up. Example permissions page for their GitHub App:

[image]

How is their GitHub App OAuth flow able to fetch my email, even though it is private? I can't find much information on this and all GitHub's [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/apps/oauth-apps/building-oauth-apps/differences-between-github-apps-and-oauth-apps) states is "GitHub Apps are preferred to OAuth apps because they use fine-grained permissions" yet Apps do not seem to offer any special email scope that would allow this. Are they using a special scope to do this or is it just because they are using a GitHub App and not a GitHub OAuth app?